# Forcing a SimpleXML Object to a string, regardless of context

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Let's say I have some XML like this

```
<channel>
  <item>
    <title>This is title 1</title>
  </item>
</channel>
```

The code below does what I want in that it outputs the title as a string

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstring);
echo $xml->channel->item->title;
```

Here's my problem.  The code below doesn't treat the title as a string in that context so I end up with a SimpleXML object in the array instead of a string.

```
$foo = array( $xml->channel->item->title );
```

I've been working around it like this

```
$foo = array( sprintf("%s",$xml->channel->item->title) );
```

but that seems ugly.

**What's the best way to force a SimpleXML object to a string, regardless of context?**

Comment: I've submitted multiple requests to PHP to implement something similar to SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS for this, and would encourage others to do the same. SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS forces elements that /could/ hold more than one string to be parsed always as just strings. Of course as others mentioned you need to know what you're getting back, but time and time again I've run into issues with .NET SOAP servers that the WSDL for ( by .NET's "magic" defaults ) prototyped every string as either mixed or an array of strings. Instead of current()'ing or typecasting, the bit just gives back a string

Answer (score 154, accepted):

**Typecast the SimpleXMLObject to a string:**

```
$foo = array( (string) $xml->channel->item->title );
```

The above code internally calls `__toString()` on the SimpleXMLObject. This method is not publicly available, as it interferes with the mapping scheme of the SimpleXMLObject, but it can still be invoked in the above manner.

Comment: That's cleaner than using a sprintf.  I like it

Comment: Note that using a function that accepts string arguments will automatically do this type casting (e.g. echo, str_replace, substr).

Comment: Thanks Aron, I thought a typecast was the way to do this but it just didnt feel right.
Now that I know the _toString method is private it makes sense.

Comment: $foo = (string) $xml->channel->item->title; 
is what I was looking for, since I don't need an array. Thanks.

Comment: +100 you just made my evening! Im new to SimpleXMLObject the vars I had extracted from it were 'printing' fine to the screen but failing my DB query...sigh!  Since when was PHP strictly typed?  ;-)

Comment: @megaSteve4 "Since when was PHP strictly typed?" - it's precisely because it's not that this needs to happen: most functions don't have a defined type context, so cannot implicitly cast to that type. Of course, they can *explicitly* cast their input params, which is why `substr` et al work. It's safer to do the cast as early as possible though, so you know all functions will see the data they expect.

Answer (score 23):

You can use the PHP function

```
strval();
```

This function returns the string values of the parameter passed to it.

Comment: @Mark Biek: It does work on objects that have `__toString()` implemented and especially in this questions case in specific, it works very well with objects of type `SimpleXMLElement`. You can compare it with the `string` cast in the accepted answer. `strval()` is a handy callback function often in conjunction with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map) and [`iterator_to_array($simpleXMLElement, false)`](http://php.net/iterator_to_array) or `SimpleXMLElement::xpath()`.

Answer (score 9):

There is native SimpleXML method [SimpleXMLElement::asXML](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php)
Depending on parameter it writes SimpleXMLElement to xml 1.0 file or just to a string:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);
$validfilename = '/temp/mylist.xml';
$xml->asXML($validfilename);    // to a file
echo $xml->asXML();             // to a string
```

Comment: I get call to an undefined function asXML so I'm guessing this is out of date now?

Comment: @Eoin Hmm... Just tested my example, it's still works fine with native php 7.3 installation

Comment: I must have had a different problem them.  My apologies.  I fixed my issue now :)

Answer (score 3):

Another ugly way to do it:

```
$foo = array( $xml->channel->item->title."" );
```

It works, but it's not pretty.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer actually returns an array containing a string, which isn't exactly what OP requested (a string).
To expand on that answer, use:

```
$foo = [ (string) $xml->channel->item->title ][0];
```

Which returns the single element of the array, a string.

Answer (score 2):

To get XML data into a php array you do this:

```
// this gets all the outer levels into an associative php array
$header = array();
foreach($xml->children() as $child)
{
  $header[$child->getName()] = sprintf("%s", $child); 
}
echo "<pre>\n";
print_r($header);
echo "</pre>";
```

To get a childs child then just do this:

```
$data = array();
foreach($xml->data->children() as $child)
{
  $header[$child->getName()] = sprintf("%s", $child); 
}
echo "<pre>\n";
print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";
```

You can expand $xml-> through each level until you get what you want
You can also put all the nodes into one array without the levels or
just about any other way you want it.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if they changed the visibility of the `__toString()` method since the accepted answer was written but at this time it works fine for me:

```php
var_dump($xml->channel->item->title->__toString());
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
string(15) "This is title 1"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try strval($xml->channel->item->title)

Answer (score 0):

There is native SimpleXML method SimpleXMLElement::asXML Depending on parameter it writes SimpleXMLElement to xml 1.0 file, Yes

```
$get_file= read file from path;
$itrate1=$get_file->node;
$html  = $itrate1->richcontent->html;


echo  $itrate1->richcontent->html->body->asXML();
 print_r((string) $itrate1->richcontent->html->body->asXML());
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put the ''. before any variable, it will convert into string.

$foo = array( ''. $xml->channel->item->title );

Answer (score -1):

The following is a recursive function that will typecast all single-child elements to a `String`:

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// FUNCTION - CLEAN SIMPLE XML OBJECT
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function cleanSimpleXML($xmlObject = ''){

    // LOOP CHILDREN
    foreach ($xmlObject->children() as $child) {

        // IF CONTAINS MULTIPLE CHILDREN
        if(count($child->children()) > 1 ){

            // RECURSE
            $child = cleanSimpleXML($child);

        }else{

            // CAST
            $child = (string)$child;

        }

    }

    // RETURN CLEAN OBJECT
    return $xmlObject;

} // END FUNCTION
```