# Getting actual value from PHP SimpleXML node

Tags: php, simplexml

```
$value = $simpleXmlDoc->SomeNode->InnerNode;
```

actually assigns a simplexml object to $value instead of the actual value of InnerNode.

If I do:

```
$value = $simpleXmlDoc->SomeNode->InnerNode . "\n";
```

I get the value. Anyway of getting the actual value without the clumsy looking `. "\n"`?

Comment: This was answered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/416548/forcing-a-simplexml-object-to-a-string-regardless-of-context

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Cast as whatever type you want (and makes sense...). By concatenating, you're implicitly casting to string, so

```
$value = (string) $xml->someNode->innerNode;
```

Answer (score 21):

You don't have to specify `innerNode`.

`$value = (string) $simpleXmlDoc->SomeNode;`

Answer (score 5):

What about using a typecast, like something like that :

```
$value = (string)$simpleXmlDoc->SomeNode->InnerNode;
```

See : [type-juggling](http://php.net/language.types.type-juggling)

Or you can probably use strval(), intval() and all that -- just probably slower, because of the function call.

Answer (score 4):

Either cast it to a string, or use it in a string context:

```
$value = (string) $simpleXmlDoc->SomeNode->InnerNode;
// OR
echo $simpleXmlDoc->SomeNode->InnerNode;
```

See the [SimpleXML reference functions guide](http://theserverpages.com/php/manual/en/ref.simplexml.php)