# Print SimpleXMLElement object

Tags: php, simplexml, printf

I have a SimpleXMLElement like this:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [trailer] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
[title] => This is the title
[link] => http://example.com
[trailer_id] => 60373
[embed] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) ) )
```

I've google for two hours now, and couldn't find how to **print the "trailer_id"**.
Could anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Interesting what text you used while searching this.

Comment: Would you mind posting the original XML?

Comment: Two hours? `:o)`. Just found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133931/getting-actual-value-from-php-simplexml-node), which looks very helpful.

Comment: seems like i just used the wrong key words for about two hours.. :P

Comment: seems like you should have started with http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Forcing a SimpleXML Object to a string, regardless of context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/416548/forcing-a-simplexml-object-to-a-string-regardless-of-context)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are objects, try:

```
echo $xml->trailer->trailer_id;
```