# each node attribute value of xml in php

Tags: php, xml

Im trying to get the catId value. But i can see only the category value.

My xml file looks below:

```
<sample>
    <Item ItemNumber="00000088" FormattedItemNumber="00000-088">
      <CompatibleModels />
        <Category CatId="160" >  test 123 </Category>
      <Images />
      <Documents />
      <RequiredItems />
    </Item>
</sample>

$xml = simplexml_load_file("test.xml");
print_r($xml);

[sample] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [ItemNumber] => 00000088
                            [FormattedItemNumber] => 00000-088
                        )

                    [Category] =>   Bags/Luggage 123 
                )
```

how can get the CatId value? Why the cateId value is missing?

Comment: You should get familiar with [simplexml and all its methods](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php). Just to put you on track: `print_r($xml->sample[0]->Item->Category->attributes()->CatId);`. And please go over [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex) because yours is not (missing the xml root element and the other samples in there).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting actual value from PHP SimpleXML node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133931/getting-actual-value-from-php-simplexml-node)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by many ways. Let's try-

```
foreach ($xml as $items) {
    echo $items->Category['CatId'];
}
```

**WORKING DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/Onqe2

Answer (score 1):

You can loop and get it by using following snippet, please refer inline documentation for explanation

```
$xml1 = simplexml_load_file("test.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
foreach ($xml1->children() as $items1) { // children mean item
    echo ($items1->category['catid']); // for category tag get catid attribute
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`print_r` doesn't really work with SimpleXML objects. But from the sample data you have provided you can simply access the `CatId` attribute using

```
echo $xml->Item->Category['CatId'];
```