# Remove newline from xml element value

Tags: php, xml, newline

I have an xml file containing 6000 element like LastName and FirstName.

I need to remove new line inside element value.

Input:

```
<info>
  <LastName>

     HOOVER

  </LastName>
</info>
```

Output:

```
<info>
  <LastName>
     HOOVER
  </LastName>
</info>
```

I've tried `preg_replace` and `str_replace` for space and `\n`, `\t`, `\r` and failed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove starting and ending spaces from XML elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337992/remove-starting-and-ending-spaces-from-xml-elements)

Comment: note that while this question is technically a duplicate the linked duplicate doesnt have an accepted answer and the given solutions are only soso in quality. maybe the linked one should be closed with this one instead.

Comment: This question asks to partially retain whitespace so that the indentation is not broken. The duplicate questions seems to be interested in more common XML whitespace normalization that is more than just a `trim` on the content (but not much more thanks to the *any whitespace character* `\s` in PCRE and it's utf-8 mode), see [a DOM based answer there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31793566/367456).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you are working with XML, you should also use one of the [XML extensions PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php) has to offer. The example below uses [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) and [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) to find all the text nodes in your XML document and [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) them.

#### Input:

```
$xml = <<< XML
<info>

  <LastName>

     HOOVER

  </LastName>

</info>
XML;
```

#### Code:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query('//text()') as $domText) {
    $domText->data = trim($domText->nodeValue);
}
$dom->formatOutput = true;
echo $dom->saveXml();
```

#### Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<info>
  <LastName>HOOVER</LastName>
</info>
```