# Extracting data from xpath reference of SimpleXMLElement Object

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

I'm trying to read an XML file into an array and I'm having a little bit of trouble. Here is what my code looks like so far:

```
 $inst = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
 foreach( $inst->xpath("record[@id='" . $range . "']") as $u ) {
      foreach($fields as $field) {
          $results[$field] = $u->$field;
      }
 }
```

But when I do `print_r($results)`, this is what's outputted:

```
Array
(
[field1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [0] => field1Data
    )

[field2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [0] => field2Data
    )

[field3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [0] => field3Data
    )
)
```

How can I get the data straight from the `SimpleXMLElement Object` and store it in the array rather than having it do this? I tried accessing it as an array like `$u->$field[0]` but that didn't work either.

Comment: simpleXml doesn't give you an array. you can build an array by iterating over the objects though.

Comment: Try casting to a string, i.e. `$results[$field] = (string)$u->$field;`

Comment: Casting it to a string worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Casting a SimpleXMLElement to string is the general solution(see [*"Forcing a SimpleXML Object to a string, regardless of context"*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/416548/367456) for the canonical question), for a complete array containing all `SimpleXMLElement`s like returned by `xpath()` or like you create it your own, a common way is to map the array onto [`trim`](http://php.net/trim):

```
$results = array_map('trim', $results);
```

or [`strval`](http://php.net/strval):

```
$results = array_map('strval', $results);
```

For example:

```
$inst    = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
list($u) = $inst->xpath("record[@id='" . $range . "']")
foreach ($fields as $field) {
    $results[$field] = $u->$field;
}

$results = array_map('strval', $results);
```