# SimpleXMLElement' is not allowed in session_write_close()

Tags: php, parsing

Im not sure what to do. im trying to make a session with my string inside of my function and parse the session outside of it , if that makes sense.... but im getting this error "SimpleXMLElement' is not allowed in session_write_close()" any suggestions on what i can do to solve it?

```
function api_info($form, &$form_state){

        $server_url = 'website api url'

        curl_setopt($ch,    CURLOPT_URL,               $server_url              );
        curl_setopt($ch,    CURLOPT_POST,              0                        );
        curl_setopt($ch,    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,                                 );    
        curl_setopt($ch,    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,        array("Expect:")         );
        curl_setopt($ch,    CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,       1                        );
        curl_setopt($ch,    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,                             );
        curl_setopt($ch,    CURLOPT_HEADER,            false                    );
        curl_setopt($ch,    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,    1                        );
        curl_setopt($ch,    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,    false                    );
        curl_setopt($ch,    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,    false                    );

        curl_setopt($ch,    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,           120                      );
        curl_setopt($ch,    CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT,       true                     );
        curl_setopt($ch,    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION,      CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1    );

        $xml_response_lead_point = curl_exec($ch);
        $xml_request_lead_point = new SimpleXMLElement($xml_response_lead_point);


        $result = reset($xml_request_lead_point->sm);

        $xml_request = $xml_request_lead_point;

        $xml_results = array(
                'lead_response' => $result,
                'results'       => $xml_request,
        );

        //dvm($xml_results['results']);
        //dvm($xml_request_lead_point);
        //dvm($a);

        $_SESSION['lead_results'] = $xml_results['results'];

        return $xml_results;
}

$lead_results = $_SESSION['lead_results'];
var_dump($lead_results);
```

Comment: you're trying to store a SimpleXML object in the session...

Comment: more so a array with the object inside, either way I gather that i am doing something incorrect here, so any advice on what to do?

Comment: I'd suggest to take out the $_SESSION asignement out of the function (It's not the solution to your problem, but it'd make your function more generic)

Answer (score 1):

You need to [`serialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) the SimpleXMLElement (or any object) before it is stored in the session and then [`unserialize()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) it for use.

```
$xml_obj = new SimpleXMLElement( $xml_string );
$_SESSION['xml_value'] = serialize( $xml_obj );
$xml_obj2 = unserialize( $_SESSION['xml_value'] );
```

Alternatively you could just save the XML string used to create the object.

Comment: it says Serialization of 'SimpleXMLElement' is not allowed in serialize() as a error now, these are the changes i made. you will notice them at the bottom http://pastebin.com/yNgDc7pW

Comment: Sorry, see this for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/416548/forcing-a-simplexml-object-to-a-string-regardless-of-context