# How do you get the string out of simple xml object?

Tags: php, arrays, object, simplexml

So I have an array of objects called $locations, each object is a `SimpleXMLElement`, each object in this array:

```
foreach ($locations as $key => $location) {
    var_dump($location);
}

die();
```

Looks like:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (9) {
  ["@attributes"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["fb"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["ll"]=>
    string(21) "44.1097932,-79.584537"
  }
  ["label"]=>
  string(8) "Bradford"
  ["name"]=>
  string(8) "Bradford"
  ["address"]=>
  string(52) "448 Holland Street West, Unit 3 Bradford, ON L3Z 2A4"
  ["phone"]=>
  string(14) "(905) 551-9463"
  ["fax"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#24 (0) {
  }
  ["mngr"]=>
  string(12) "OPENING SOON"
  ["email"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#25 (0) {
  }
  ["hours"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#26 (0) {
  }
}
```

Now I want the string, not the objet, but the string `name` from each of these objects in an associative array with a key of `$key` and a `$value` of of `name`. So I did:

```
$organizedLocations = array ();
foreach ($locations as $key => $location) {
    var_dump($location, $location->name);
    $organizedLocations[$key] = $location->name;
}

die();
```

Notice the `var_dump`. `$location->name` is:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#23 (1) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "Bradford"
}
```

This is not what I want. I want, in this case: "Bradford", not some object with a string.
I tried doing `$location->name->0` I even tried looping over `$location->name` in a `foreach` and I tried `$location->name[0]` none of those worked.

How do I get `Bradford` out of the object and into my array as a value to the `$key`?

Comment: Why was this down voted? I showed clear examples, the problem is well out lined. What am I missing? Where is the feedback, to make the question better?

Comment: This link should help you:

[Converting a SimpleXML Object to an Array][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167279/converting-a-simplexml-object-to-an-array

Comment: @Yolo, this is probably the best solution IF you can afford the overhead of encoding and decoding the XML to JSON. I found it to be a bit slow and high on RAM consumption on large (3k+ objects) XML objects. But yeah, generally that's what I'd do:)

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this is to cast it to a string as then I will get my actual value I want to then store in an array:

```
 (string) $location->name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate. Maybe these threads are what you need

[Forcing a SimpleXML Object to a string, regardless of context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416548/forcing-a-simplexml-object-to-a-string-regardless-of-context)

[Get value from SimpleXMLElement Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867575/get-value-from-simplexmlelement-object)

Comment: *Possible duplicate* ? Possible comment?!