# Loop through xml nodes with simplexml

Tags: php, xml, foreach, simplexml

Im trying to create a table of Jobs on my site, pulling info from an xml feed I have access to... I've looked at various examples online and videos but I can't seem to understand how it works. My xml feed returns the following node structure:

```
<OutputVacancyAsXml>
  <Vacancy>
    <VacancyID></VacancyID>
    <Job></Job>
    <ClosingDate></ClosingDate>
  </Vacancy>
</OutputVacancyAsXml>
```

I've had success with pulling through one item with this code:

```
<?php
    $x = simplexml_load_file('https://www.octopus-hr.co.uk/recruit/OutputVacancyAsXml.aspx?CompanyID=400-73A3BCA1-D952-4BA6-AADB-D8BF3B495DF6');
    echo $x->Vacancy[5]->Job;
?>
```

But converting it to foreach seems to be where I'm struggling. Heres the code I have tried so far with no luck;

```
<?php
$html = "";
$url = "https://www.octopus-hr.co.uk/recruit/OutputVacancyAsXml.aspx?CompanyID=400-73A3BCA1-D952-4BA6-AADB-D8BF3B495DF6";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
  $title = $xml->OutputVacancyAsXml->Vacancy[$i]->job;
  $html .= "<p>$title</p>";

}
echo $html;
?>
```

Thanks all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok looks like I found a solution. Heres the code that worked for me plus it contains a little bit of code that pulls out duplicated (it was displaying each item 4 times!)...

```
<?php


              $x = simplexml_load_file('https://www.octopus-hr.co.uk/recruit/OutputVacancyAsXml.aspx?CompanyID=400-73A3BCA1-D952-4BA6-AADB-D8BF3B495DF6');

            $num = count($x->Vacancy);

            //echo "num is $num";

            $stopduplicates = array();

            for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++) {


           $job = $x->Vacancy[$i]->Job;
              $closingdate = $x->Vacancy[$i]->ClosingDate;
              // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/416548/forcing-a-simplexml-object-to-a-string-regardless-of-context
              $vacancyid = (string) $x->Vacancy[$i]->VacancyID; 


                if (!in_array($vacancyid, $stopduplicates)) {  




              echo '
                <tr class="job-row">
                  <td class="job-cell">'.$job.'</td>
                  <td class="date-cell">'.$closingdate.'</td>
                  <td class="apply-cell">
                    <a href="https://www.octopus-hr.co.uk/recruit/application/apply.aspx?cid=400-73A3BCA1-D952-4BA6-AADB-D8BF3B495DF6&VacancyID='.$vacancyid.'" target="_blank" class="btn btn-teal btn-md btn-job" role="button">Apply Here</a>
                  </td>
                </tr>';       
                }
             $stopduplicates[] = $vacancyid; 
            } //print_r($stopduplicates);
          ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php#example-6331)

> Note:
>
> Properties ($movies->movie in previous example) are not arrays. They
>   are iterable and accessible objects.

With that kept in mind you can simple run over the nodes with `foreach`

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
foreach ($xml->OutputVacancyAsXml->Vacancy as $vacanacy)
{
    echo (string)$vacanacy->Job; // Echo out the Job Title
}
```

Comment: Thanks  KhorneHoly - So I have put it together and come up with this, but it doesn't seems to work...

<?php
$html = "";
$url = "https://www.octopus-hr.co.uk/recruit/OutputVacancyAsXml.aspx?CompanyID=400-73A3BCA1-D952-4BA6-AADB-D8BF3B495DF6";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
foreach ($xml->OutputVacancyAsXml->Vacancy as $vacanacy)
{
    echo (string)$vacanacy->Job; // Echo out the Job Title
}
?>

Comment: Not sure I'm supposed to add that there KhorneHoly - No Code area by the looks of it...